# On largest box not containing integer vector solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, integers, diophantine-approximation, linear-diophantine-equations

I am trying to understand the largest cube in $\Bbb Z^4$ around origin not containing integer vector $(a,b,c,d)$ solutions to $$aBD+bBC+cAD+dAC=0$$ where $gcd(AB,CD)=gcd(AC,BD)=1$ when $n<A,B,C,D<2n$ and $n/8<|A-B|,|C-D|,|A-C|,|A-D|,|B-C|,|B-D|<n/4$ holds?

Is the box $c'n^{2/3}$ in length around origin for some constant $0<c'$? That is a vector $(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb Z^4$ with $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|<c'n^{2/3}$ exists?

This is where I get the $2/3$ value.
$$aBD+bBC+cAD+dAC=0$$ 
$$B(aD+bC)=-A(cD+dC)$$ 
$$cD+dC=\ell B$$
$$aD+bC=-\ell A$$

If size of $\ell$ is $n^\eta$ then size of $\ell B$ is size of $cD+dD$ is $n^{1+\eta}$. We have $n^{2\eta}$ values in $cd$ and $n^{2\eta}$ values in $ab$ and we want to hit $\ell B$ and $\ell A$ (a total of $2n^{\eta}$ possibilities) of a total of $n^{2(1+\eta)}$ possibilities. The expected intersection is 
$$\frac{n^{2\eta}n^{2\eta}2n^{\eta}}{n^{2(1+\eta)}}=\frac{2n^{3\eta}}{n^2}$$

If $3\eta>2$ or $2/3<\eta$ we have expected intersection $\gg1$.

Comment: @Willjagy I thought you had answers.... were they incorrect?

Comment: @Willjagy I am trying to get back to this problem to prove lower bound on shortest lattice vector in a probabilistic sense. I think you had your code here. It will help me get some statistics. Could you please repost?

Comment: @willjagy Do you think the expected intersection idea holds for similar random assumptions except we also have $A-B=C-D$ a random prime?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066365/on-largest-box-expected-size-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

September 18.

I wrote my test programs with fixed integers $A,B,C,D,$ positive and pairwise coprime. I called the variables $w,x,y,z.$  The homogeneous linear diophantine equation to be considered is
$$  BDw + BC x + AD y + ACz = 0  $$ 
The article that showed me how to find a basis for the lattice was [L. W. Griffiths, A Note on Linear Homogeneous Diophantine Equations, Bulletin AMS 1946.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183509584)

Short version, Lois Wilfred Griffiths was a student of L. E. Dickson. Her 1927 Ph.D. dissertation was "Certain quaternary quadratic forms and diophantine equations by generalized quaternion algebras."

As $\gcd(A,B) = 1,$ we solve
$$  MB-NA = 1.  $$
Then, a three by four matrix whose rows give a basis of the indicated lattice is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
-A & 0 & B & 0 \\
0 & A & 0 & -B  \\
MC & -MD & -NC & ND 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Next, a (real) unit vector in the 3-space containing the  lattice, that is orthogonal to the first two rows, is
$$ \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt {A^2 + B^2} \sqrt{C^2 + D^2}} \right) \left( BC, -BD, AC, -AD \right). $$
The  length of   $(MC, -MD, -NC, ND)$ projected onto the unit vector above is exactly
$$   \sqrt { \frac{C^2 + D^2}{A^2 + B^2}  }.  $$ As a result, the fundamental parallelopiped has volume precisely 
$$ \sqrt {A^2 + B^2} \sqrt{C^2 + D^2} $$
Then, the Gram matrix obtained by taking the basis matrix times its transpose has determinant 
$$ \left( A^2 + B^2 \right) \left( C^2 + D^2 \right) $$
From formula (12) on page 92 of Dickson's Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers, we find that the squared norm of the shortest nonzero vector in the lattice is no larger than
$$ \frac{4}{3} \; \; \sqrt[3]{ \left( A^2 + B^2 \right) \left( C^2 + D^2 \right)} $$
The absolute values of $w,x,y,z$ can therefore be no larger than 
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} \; \; \sqrt[6]{ \left( A^2 + B^2 \right) \left( C^2 + D^2 \right)} $$

If, as originally stipulated, we have some positive $n$ with
$$  n \leq A,B,C,D \leq 2n,$$ we get
$$       |w|,|x|,|y|,|z| \leq    \frac{2 \cdot 16^{1/6}}{\sqrt 3} \; \; n^{2/3}                $$

September 19.

Worth recording how we know we have found a basis for the lattice. 
$$  BDw + BC x + AD y + ACz = 0  $$
$$  MB-NA = 1.  $$
$$  C(Bx + Az) + D(Bw + Ay) = 0.  $$
$$  C(Bx + Az) =  -D(Bw + Ay) .  $$
$$ \gcd(C,D) = 1. $$
$$    C | (Bw + Ay) $$
Let $r \in Z,$
$$  Bw + Ay = Cr, \; \; \;  \mbox{therefore} \; \; Bx + Az = -Dr.  $$
$$  Bw + Ay = C ( MB-NA)r,$$
$$  B(w - MCr) = -A(y+NCr).  $$
$$ \gcd(A,B)=1, A | (w - MCr), \mbox{define} \; \; p, $$
$$  w - MCr = -Ap, \; \; \;  \mbox{therefore} \; \; y+NCr = Bp.  $$
Return to
$$  Bx + Az = -Dr,  $$
$$  Bx + Az = -D( MB-NA)r,  $$
$$  B(x + MDr) = -A(z-NDr)  $$
$$ A | (x + MDr) , \mbox{define} \; \; q, $$
$$  x + MDr = Aq, \; \; \;  \mbox{therefore} \; \; z-NDr = -Bq.  $$
Together,
$$  w = MCr  -Ap, \; \;  x = - MDr + Aq, \; \;  y= -NCr + Bp, \; \;z=NDr  -Bq. $$
$$  (w,x,y,z) = p(-A,0,B,0) + q (0,A,0,-B) + r (MC,-MD, -NC,ND).  $$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this explicit bound is actually pretty accurate. Would you know the corresponding bound for $$\begin{bmatrix}ABCD&A^2C^2&A^2D^2&B^2C^2&B^2D^2&A^2CD&B^2CD&C^2AB&D^2AB\end{bmatrix}?$$ Is it $c'\cdot n^{1/2}$ at some $c'>0$?

Comment: By this I mean for $$ABCDa+A^2C^2b+A^2D^2c+B^2C^2d+B^2D^2e+A^2CDf+B^2CDg+C^2ABh+D^2ABi=0$$ is it $|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|,|e|,|f|,|g|,|h|,|i|\leq c'\cdot n^{1/2}$ at some $c'>0$?

Comment: The nullspace matrix for this is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-A&0&0&0&0&B&0&0&0\\
-B&0&0&0&0&0&A&0&0\\
-C&0&0&0&0&0&0&D&0\\
-D&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&C\\
0&-D&0&0&0&C&0&0&0\\
0&0&-B&0&0&0&0&0&A\\
0&0&0&-A&0&0&0&B&0\\
0&0&0&0&-C&0&D&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Visually the bound $c'\cdot n$ at some $c'>0$ looks correct but related heuristics like one in my post gives $c'\cdot n^{1/2}$ at some $c'>0$.

Comment: I tested in mathematica. Infact the $\sqrt n$ bound holds up. This is very strange.

Comment: you are not using the $n/8<|A-B|,\dots<n/4$ criterion at all.  So does this upper bound of
$$       |w|,|x|,|y|,|z| \leq    \frac{2 \cdot 16^{1/6}}{\sqrt 3} \; \; n^{2/3}                $$ have a matching lower bound? That will show it for all coprime quadruples $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: I am asking this since your simulation also shows a smaller exponent fails and so is this exponent tight? What we have is only an upper bound. There should be a way to get a matching lower bound that works for any $A,B,C,D$ as long as they are mutually coprime (I think even $A,B$ coprime and $C,D$ coprime suffices as long as they is no equal pair).

Comment: By matching lower bound I mean $\max(|w|,|x|,|y|,|z|)>c''\cdot n^{2/3}$ form lower bound that works at any coprime $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: I do not think $c''\cdot n^{2/3}$ can hold. But it is possible $c''\cdot n^{1/2}$ might. Is there a way to show?

Comment: your simulation also suggests fail at $n^{1/2}$ but I think there has to be a constant.

Comment: I think even $c''\cdot n^{1/2}$ lower bound is optimistic.... something else is happening.

Answer (score 1):

October 4, 2017

You had a question for a few hours about doubling the dimension; maybe that was yesterday.  We are looking for a basis for the lattice inside $\mathbb Z^8$ of vectors orthogonal to
$$ (EBD, EBC, EAD, EAC,FBD, FBC, FAD, FAC )  $$ 
where we define integers such that
$$ MB - NA =1,  $$
$$ JD-KC=1.  $$
A 7 by 8 matrix with rows giving a basis is
$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
  A & 0  & -B  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0& -A  &0  & B &0  & 0 & 0 &0 \\
  0& 0 &0  &0  & A &0 & -B  & 0  \\
  0& 0 & 0 &0  & 0 & -A  &0  & B \\
  MC& -MD & -NC  & ND  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & MC & -MD & -NC & ND \\
  FMJ & -FMK  & -FNJ  & FNK  & -EMJ  & EMK  & ENJ  & -ENK 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The resulting Gram matrix is
$$
G = R R^T =
\scriptsize
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
  A^2 + B^2 & 0  & 0  & 0 & (AM+BN)C & 0 & (AM+BN)FJ  \\
  0& A^2 + B^2  &0  & 0 &  (AM+BN)D  & 0 & (AM+BN)FK  \\
  0& 0 & A^2 + B^2  &0  & 0 &  (AM+BN)C & -(AM+BN)EJ    \\
  0& 0 & 0 & A^2 + B^2  & 0 &  (AM+BN)D  &-(AM+BN)EK   \\
  (AM+BN)C& (AM+BN)D & -NC  & ND  & (M^2 + N^2)(C^2 + D^2) & 0 &  (M^2 + N^2)(JC+KD)F\\
 0 & 0 & (AM+BN)C & (AM+BN)C & 0 &(M^2 + N^2)(C^2 + D^2) & -(M^2 + N^2)(JC+KD)E  \\
   (AM+BN)FJ & (AM+BN)FK  & -(AM+BN)EJ  &-(AM+BN)EK  & (M^2 + N^2)(JC+KD)F  &-(M^2 + N^2)(JC+KD)E   &  (M^2 + N^2)(J^2 + K^2)(E^2 + F^2)
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The amazing thing is all the cancellation as
$$  \det G = (A^2 + B^2)(C^2 + D^2)(E^2 + F^2)  $$

As before, the smallest element of the indicated quadratic form is no more than an explicit constant times
$$  \left( \det G \right)^{1/7}.  $$
Each element of the vector in $\mathbb Z^8$ that achieves that quadratic form value is no larger than a constant times
$$  \left( \det G \right)^{1/14}.  $$

It is pretty clear that this process continues; repeat to get, in dimension 16,
$$  \det G = (A^2 + B^2)(C^2 + D^2)(E^2 + F^2)(H^2 + I^2)  $$
with exponents given as $1/15$ then $1/30.$

Here are pages 136-137 of [Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms,](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html) which you should purchase. 
[image]

Comment: I figured the process out up to constants (but thank you for making it explicit) and the actual query I have struggle with is here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282681/does-the-siegel-diophantine-bound-agree-here-almost-surely where we need a lower bound for shortest vector in average sense. It should be doable looking at the discrimininant but I am still thinking on it and if you have something important for that it will be great.

Comment: The struggle is because it is clear from your computations that the upper bound is not tight for all situations. However those situations should intuitively have much smaller measure asymptotically.