# Reference for Noam Elkies comments on integral lattices and fundamental parallelotope

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

ORIGINAL: I would like to find some more detailed references to explain  2012 comments of Prof. Noam Elkies at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103152/determinant-of-integer-lattice-basis-of-l-x-1-ldots-x-n-a-1x-1-cdotsa

Here are screen captures 
[image]
[image]

The recent questions I answered that got me interested were:

[Basis for the kernel of linear map for linear Diophantine equation in three variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488074/basis-for-the-kernel-of-linear-map-for-linear-diophantine-equation-in-three-vari/2488307#2488307)

[On largest box not containing integer vector solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392683/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions)

[On largest box not containing integer vector solutions-$II$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456368/on-largest-box-not-containing-integer-vector-solutions-ii)

In case of interest, here is an article on a  recent breakthrough: http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201702/rnoti-p102.pdf

Answer (score 2):

August 2018: this is also in the section called "The orthogonal lattice" in the article Merkle-Hellman Revisited: A Cryptanalysis of the Qu-Vanstone Cryptosystem Based on Group Factorizations, by P. Nguyen and J. Stern (1997). [Link to a ps version](https://www.di.ens.fr/~stern/data/St67b.ps)

Found it. I am quite fond of a book by Wolfgang Ebeling called *Lattices and Codes.* I have the second edition, in which all relevant material is in pages 1-5, and this **Proposition 1.2** and its proof are on page 5. In the third edition, the statement of **Proposition 1.2** is on page 4, with the proof split on pages 4 and 5.

Ebeling also points out the proof in [Looijenga and Peters(1981)](https://eudml.org/doc/89474). The directly relevant discussion is just pages 153-154, (pdf pages [9],[10]), while this is Lemma (2.3) on page 154. The  section devoted to lattices is pages 153-157, pdf [9]-[13]. Oh, well. For some reason the jpegs from the article are not showing properly. Sigh. Or, having tried one pasting the imgur address in a new tab, it is just not appearing here within the first minute...

[image]
[image]